# Annoation Route not work in symfony 4.2.8

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I work with symfony 4 for [create page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html).

create ArticleController like this:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/")
         * @Method({"GET"})
        */

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Hello !!!</body></html>'
        );

    }
}
```

I install annotation using composer and this is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

And add this `.htaccess` file into public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, When I check with browser url:`smfony.local` I see symfony welcome page. I check route using `routes.yaml` file and my route work fine and true(show Hello ! ! ! message) But annotation route not work for me.

How do can I fix this problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to move the annotation before the route:

```
/**
* @Route("/", name="index")
*/
public function index()
{

    return new Response(
        '<html><body>Hello !!!</body></html>'
    );

}
```

Also make sure you add annotations `composer require annotations`